# Transforming large vertical set of data into multiple tables in excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, powerquery

I have a very large set of data stored vertically which I need to separate into multiple tables.

Currently the data is stored as such when exported (repeated for about 3k rows down)

Raw data:

[image]

The date is stored is A1 and beneath is each group of data. Each group is separated by a header row with a name in the first column and no column labels for column 2 and column 3.

The Column 1 header for each "Table" in the data range is the name of the "table" which it shows data for, and the cells in column 1 are identical for each grouping. So for "Name1" the cells beneath will be same as the cells beneath "Name2", and the cells beneath Column2 and Column3's headers will be the data that changes. Which is what has become my biggest headache to solve. The problem is this is the only way which the system exports that data.

I'm attempting to select the entire range of data, so three columns wide and a good few thousand rows down and apply either a macro or SQL automation to convert it into multiple tables.

The format for the tables I'm attempting to generate is keeping the name in the already existing header rows in column 1, and setting the second and third columns of each header row to "Header2" and "Header3". Additionally I'd like to take the date from cell A1 and concatenate it with the Name stored in the first header, EG "Name-19/02/2024" and set it as the table name.
EG:
Transformed data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipCBA.png

I've already attempted to perform this using macros however the nature of the problem extends my knowledge in VBA due to the complexity of the transformation, I have the assumption that it may be easier solved in SQL or PowerQuery? So I'm open to using those if its a more elegant solution.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)  Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: Generating/creating multiple tables is tough. Could you not just keep it as one well-formed table (Columns: Date | Name | Header 1 | Header 2) and then use filters etc.. Doing this is relatively easy in PowerQuery.

Comment: The issue is the organization of the exported data which prevents this method, I've edited the post to add some clarity as I now realize its not as clear.

Comment: Is cell A1 the only date on the sheet?

Comment: Yes the date only appears in cell A1

Comment: My suggestion is go from here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFk24.png to here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Q2p.png with just PowerQuery (no need for VBA). Then you will have one well formed table that you can use. If interested, can post answer on the same.

Comment: The solution seems like it could work, I'd be happy if you could post it yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Assuming that cell A contains the only date on the sheet.
- ***Note:*** `EG "Name-19/02/2024" and set it as the table name`. Table names must be unique; for instance, in your screenshot, two tables have the same headers (with the first cell being "Name"). It throws error 1004.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, iR As Long, oRng
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range, sDate As String
    Dim oCol As Collection, oSht As Worksheet
    Const COL2_NAME = "Header2"
    Const COL3_NAME = "Header3"
    Set oSht = ActiveSheet ' modify as needed
    With oSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    ' Load data into array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    sDate = arrData(1, 1)
    Set oCol = New Collection
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        ' Locate the header row of each table
        If Len(arrData(i, 2) & arrData(i, 3)) = 0 Then
            If Len(arrData(i, 1)) > 0 Then
                ' Populate header
                arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i, 1) & "-" & sDate
                arrData(i, 2) = COL2_NAME
                arrData(i, 3) = COL3_NAME
                If iR > 0 Then
                    oCol.Add oSht.Range("A" & iR).Resize(i - iR, 3), CStr(i)
                End If
                iR = i
            ElseIf i = UBound(arrData) Then
                oCol.Add oSht.Range("A" & iR).Resize(i - iR, 3), CStr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    rngData.Value = arrData
    ' Create table (ListObject)
    For Each oRng In oCol
        ' table with default name
        oSht.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, oRng, , xlYes
        ' table with customized name
        ' oSht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, oRng, , xlYes).Name = oRng(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yes A1 contains the only date in the sheet. To use the macro do I highlight the data? Or must I specify the range within the macro itself?

Comment: No. Make sure the data in on the activesheet. Please backup your file before testing.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: Had a rogue value in a header cell and now its working fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This proposed answer is to create a well-formed table via PowerQuery.

Assuming you have the following in Excel:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19/02/2024 |  |  |
| Bob |  |  |
| a | 11 | 111 |
| b | 12 | 112 |
| c | 13 | 113 |
| d | 14 | 114 |
| e | 15 | 115 |
| f | 16 | 116 |
| g | 17 | 117 |
| Bill |  |  |
| a | 21 | 221 |
| b | 22 | 222 |
| c | 23 | 223 |
| d | 24 | 224 |
| e | 25 | 225 |
| f | 26 | 226 |
| g | 27 | 227 |
| 20/02/2024 |  |  |
| Bob |  |  |
| a | 31 | 311 |
| b | 32 | 312 |
| c | 33 | 313 |
| d | 34 | 314 |
| e | 35 | 315 |
| f | 36 | 316 |
| g | 37 | 317 |
| Bill |  |  |
| a | 41 | 421 |
| b | 42 | 422 |
| c | 43 | 423 |
| d | 44 | 424 |
| e | 45 | 425 |
| f | 46 | 426 |
| g | 47 | 427 |

Load the data above in PowerQuery and then use the following script:

```
let
  Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Book2.xlsx"), null, true),
  Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
  #"Add Date" = Table.AddColumn(Sheet1_Sheet, "Date", each try Date.From([Column1]) otherwise null),
  #"Add Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Date", "Name", each if [Column2] = null and [Column3] = null and [Date] = null then [Column1] else null),
  #"FillDown DateName" = Table.FillDown(#"Add Name", {"Date", "Name"}),
  #"FilterOut Headers" = Table.SelectRows(#"FillDown DateName", each ([Column2] <> null))
in
  #"FilterOut Headers"
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Comment: I ended up going with @taller 's solution once I got it working however this one works as well. TYSM!